# Show processes running on remote computer using WMI

Tags: remote, wmi, windows

I'm using WMI in order to run commands on a remote machine. For now, and I know it's as it should be, the process which is being run is not shown on the screen of the remote, I can only see it running when I open the task manager.

Like I said, I know it's ok.

My question is: Is there any way to overcome this issue and force the remote to show the executed process? (e.g. see calc's gui when I open it, or show notepad or cmd etc.).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With WMI you only receive the PID back to you, you can't interact with it.

Other options like PSExec and WinRS/WinRM won't allow you to achieve this.

On WinRS/WinRM you can interact with a console application, like CMD.exe

One workaround I can think of is to use an XServer and connect to it via SSH, but that would be the *Nix way to do it.

The Windows way to do it is to use [Terminal Services RemoteApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753844%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)